# Servlet session cookie tampering and security

Tags: java, session, servlets

On the server side, after a successful logon, I execute :

```
HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("user", subject.getUser().getId());
session.setAttribute("logged", true);
```

I then assume that the user is logged in. When the user navigates to a secure page in order to save or delete a record from my database, I run this code.

```
HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if (session.getAttribute("user")!=null && session.getAttribute("logged"))
{
     //delete a record using the authority of the user.
}
```

My concern is that a client can tamper its browser cookie with a different user id. The database request would be initiated with a different user, skipping the login process.

Can java session identify tampering, or should I digitally sign the session by including this line

```
session.setAttribute("signature", hash(secretkey + subject.getUser().getId());
```

then verify that the signature is valid before changing the database.

```
if (session.getAttribute("signature").equals(hash(secretkey + session.getAttribute("user"))
{
    //delete a record using the authority of the user.
}
```

Comment: Even though your assumptions about how Java sessions work were mistaken (as explained in the answer below), I applaud your thinking about security. You definitely shouldn't trust anything that the client sends you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you examined your cookies? Are you actually keeping the user-id in a cookie, and if yes, what for?
The server side session object can't be accessed from the client side, that would be a huge security problem.

If your code is correct, there's no reason or advantage in using a hash.

Comment: So, the java session only stores a small string on the client side. And such string is used to retrieve all stored objects on the server side?

Comment: Yeah, like a key to a HashMap.